# isdigit not working for me

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def listMaker(a, b):
    if b.isdigit() == False:
         print("Sorry is not a valid input")
    else:
         newList = [a] * b
         return newList
```

I am getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: `isdigit` is a method on strings, not integers.  If you have an integer it is already guaranteed to be all numeric, because it's a numeric type.  How are you assigning an initial value to `b`?

Comment: Did you mean `if not isinstance(b, int):`? Note that `if not b.isdigit():` is much more readable than the comparison to `False`.

Answer (score 3):

`isdigit()` is a method of a `str` class. Depending on what are trying to achieve, either convert b to string first:

```
if not str(b).isdigit()
```

or (and better), use `isinstance` to check attribute types:

```
if not isinstance(b, int)
```

Comment: Just to add, you might want to `str().strip()`. If the string contains a newline character (from running a command via `subprocess`) then `isdigit()` fails derpily.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you already have integer, if don't sure you can do:

```
if isinstance(b, int):
    print("Sorry is not a valid input")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just wrap the input in `int` instead.

```
def listMaker(a, b):
    try:
        b = int(b)
    except ValueError:
         print("Sorry is not a valid input")
    else:
         newList = [a] * b
         return newList
```

Example:

```
>>> listMaker(1, '4')
[1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> listMaker(1, 'josh')
Sorry is not a valid input
>>> listMaker(1, '4.2')
Sorry is not a valid input
```

This would be the [pythonic EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like only the `string` type has this method, not `int`. See [there](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Docstring**:

```
S.isdigit() -> bool
```

*Return True if **all characters in S are digits*** and *there is at least one character in S, False otherwise.*

Let's try it in python shell.

```
>>> aaa = '123'
>>> aaa.isdigit()
True

>>> bbb = '123a4'
>>> bbb.isdigit()
False

>>> ccc = 123
>>> ccc.isdigit()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

We can also compare **dir(aaa)** with **dir(bbb)** and **dir(ccc)** for details.